# MD5 File Concatenation

Tags: linux, bash, unix

dears,

can any one help me on

here is an example md5 file which contains several checksums. (between the dashes)
You will see that 6 are for files in on subdir and 2 are for files in the directory:

```
------------------------------------------------
# MD5 checksums generated by MD5summer (http://www.md5summer.org)
# Generated 6/25/2021 9:54:07 AM
8a7e254a35f0d1cd91d70c10af0e2093 *8.1.11/AIX/Server/SP_8.1.11_AIX_OC_ML.bin.bin
5190d58ac2e2da827a2ac69dd7315378 *8.1.11/AIX/Server/SP_8.1.11_AIX_SERSTG_AGT_ML.bin
abde96143ffa51bfa65f781831313194 *8.1.11/Client/AIX/SP_CLIENT_8.1.11_AIX_ML.tar.gz
a5e4883f16f1ee40517f3009a402d7c9 *8.1.11/Client/Linux/SP_CLIENT_8.1.11_LIN86_ML.tar.gz.tar.gz
d3bccef988b0b9b493e2bfc682e26545 *8.1.11/Linux/8.1.11.000-IBM-SPSRV-Linuxx86_64.bin
adea74d6f7e29d4b707f6dcde4713048 *8.1.11/WIN/SP_8.1.11_WIN64_OC_ML.bin
c61ef98d9944bbdb2dc7329d0b4a9ffa *SP_CLIENT_8.1.12_LIN86_ML.tar.gz
5ec6347982179ce1463d7ac8cad61a28 *SP_CLIENT_8.1.12_LINPOW_LE_ML.tar.gz
------------------------------------------------
```

Files such as these will need to be added to a single aster MD5 file.
You will effectively work out where each md5 is and then will need to change the “*” for “*//” and then added it to the master MD5 file.
can anyone have script for this

Comment: Can you provide the expected output. I did not get anything from your explanations.

Comment: the expected output at the end should be on one master MD5 file for all , each md5 is and then will need to change the “*” for “*/<actual path of folder where md file is located>/” and then added it to the master MD5 file.

Comment: So, what have you tried so far? How far did you get? What are you stuck on? We're here to help, but we're not a free scripting service: show us your effort.

Comment: @AnasSalehm show, do not explain. Edit your question

Comment: Also: are dashes part of the file, or just your attempt at making the file contents stand out in the formatting chaos?

Comment: That really sounds like homework/assignment to me